# A counter that increases and decreases depending on other elements

Tags: java

Im trying to make a PlantsVSZombies game. The player has initially 50 suns in order to buy plants. I want to make a counter which decreases whenever I buy plants but also increases continously if I have sunflowers present. Any ideas how I could do it? And thank you.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some code you already tried so that the community can help you

Comment: Just an idea. Can multi-threading be used?

Answer (score 0):

In pseudocode:

```
int counter = 50;

if(....)
    ...
    counter--;
else if (....)
    ...
    counter++;
```

It would be easier for us if you displayed what code you have tried and what issues you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

For the next time, try to add some information about your classes and how you are planning to write all your code. For this question and with this information you can try to just manage that with one Integer value:

```
int suns = 50;

public sunsCounter(bool increase){
    if(increase){
       this.suns +=1
    }else{
       this.suns -=1
}
```

I'ts just an idea and it's so basic, obviously, you have to create some classes to manage that and operate with this class objects.